# Missing com.android.tools.build.gradle4.1 in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Here is my `build.gradle` file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And here is gradle-wrapper:

```
#Fri Jan 12 02:39:29 EST 2018
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4.1-all.zip
```

The full error trace is here:

```
Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'CryptoGallery'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/home/xavi/android-studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1/gradle-4.1.pom
         file:/home/xavi/android-studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1/gradle-4.1.jar
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1/gradle-4.1.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1/gradle-4.1.jar
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1/gradle-4.1.pom
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1/gradle-4.1.jar
     Required by:
         project :

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
```

I took a look in the directory `/home/xavi/android-studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1/` and saw that I *do* have a gradle `4.1` build, but it doesn't contain a simple `.jar` like the others do. It's the full download from the official gradle website. It contains many executables, but none labeled `gradle-4.1.jar` like the others.

Edit: After changing `classpath` to the correct line, android studio prompts me to update my gralde to 4.4.1, and I get a traceback.

Answer (score 6):

Don't confuse **gradle** with the **androd plugin** for gradle.

Change:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1'
```

with:

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
```

More info [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html).

Comment: That's odd, because trying to build my project with fdroid still throws `Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.1. Current version is 3.2.1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /home/xavi/gitlab/fdroiddata/build/com.photocrypt.CryptoGallery/app/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-4.1-all.zip
`

Comment: You are using the 4.4.1 so it should be valid. Try to check in your settings if you are using the wrapper instead of a local version of gradle. Finally try to clean the cache.

Comment: @Astrum the current version is 3.1.2 fyi :)

Comment: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/

Comment: @GrayProgrammerz it isn't the right repo. Check the google repo: https://maven.google.com/web/index.html?q=gradle#com.android.tools.build:gradle

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti That link will tell you list of versions available to be added after `build:gradle:x.x.x'`.

Comment: @GrayProgrammerz Yes, but your link is obsolete and doesn't contain the latest releases since it is not the google maven repo but the apache maven repo.

Comment: Oh may be. because I am using visual studio 2017 with gradle.